# How to move/animate components created by repeater in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, repeater

I have a component named `Tile` in Tile.qml, which I want to create by a Repeater. Tile.qml is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: tile

    property string tileLabel: label.text
    property int tileSize: height

    width: 50
    height: tileSize
    color: "green"
    border.color: Qt.lighter(color)
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

    Text {
        id: label
        color: "white";
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.bottom
        text: tileLabel
    }
}
```

And my main.qml is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 552; height: 300
    color: "#3C3C3C"
    border.color: Qt.lighter(color)

    Row {
        id: tilesRow
        anchors.margins: 8
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        spacing: 4
        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: 10
            delegate: Tile {
                tileSize: Math.random() * 100 + 1
                tileLabel: tileSize
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: button
        width: 100
        height: 30
        color: "gray"
        focus: true

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "white"
            text: "Button"
        }
        MouseArea {
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            onEntered: { button.color = Qt.lighter("blue")}
            onExited: { button.color = "gray" }
            onPressed: { button.color = "blue" }
            onReleased: { button.color = Qt.lighter("blue") }
            onClicked: func()
        }
    }
}
```

I need to sort the tiles when the button is clicked so that the tiles are in ascending order by their labels. I can access the labels of the tiles using `repeater.itemAt(i).tileSize`. How can I animate the movement of tiles as they are moved/swapped?

Comment: This could help: [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Small example:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        property var word: ['H','e','l','l','o','!']
        id: row
        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: row.word.length
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: delegate;
                width: 100
                height: 100
                property int pos
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 36
                    color: "white"
                    text: row.word[index]
                }

                Behavior on x {
                    ParallelAnimation {
                        PropertyAnimation {
                            duration: 500
                            easing.type: Easing.InOutBack
                        }
                        SequentialAnimation {
                            PropertyAnimation {
                                target: delegate
                                property: "y"
                                from: 0
                                to: delegate.pos == 1 ? 20 : -20
                                duration: 250
                            }
                            PropertyAnimation {
                                target: delegate
                                property: "y"
                                from: delegate.pos == 1 ? 20 : -20
                                to: 0
                                duration: 250
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Behavior on rotation {
                    RotationAnimation {
                        direction: RotationAnimation.Clockwise
                        duration: 300
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            var element1 = repeater.itemAt(Math.round(Math.random() * (repeater.count - 1)));
            var element2 = repeater.itemAt(Math.round(Math.random() * (repeater.count - 1)));
            if(element1 === element2) {
                element1.rotation = element1.rotation + 90;
            } else {
                element1.pos = 1;
                element2.pos = 2;
                var temp = element1.x;
                element1.x = element2.x;
                element2.x = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small example but also nice example! :)

Comment: Nice! But if the model is C++ how to sort it really?